# During attack by Wahhabi Muslims of Saudi on Karbala city in Iraq, how many Shia Muslims were killed?

Tags: islam, iraq, saudi-arabia

There are different stats about this. It is mentioned in different references, numbers ranging from 4000 to even 120,000.

What is correct casualty count?

Also did this attack really happened in history?

Comment: Got a date for this?

Comment: @T.E.D. yes but I do not know if they are valid or not. http://www.terrorism-illuminati.com/wahhabis and http://www.fsmitha.com/h2/ch17arab.html and http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fa&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.valiasr-aj.com%2Ffa%2Fpage.php%3Fbank%3Dkhabar%3Dr68e%26id%3D3163

Comment: Yes, the attack did happen in history. This was one of the topic I learned during an Islamology lecture. However I don't remember the casualty count.

Comment: Here is an academic book referencing the incident. http://books.google.co.id/books?id=BXJqeTr6p78C&lpg=PA28&ots=z0oxi6ptxI&dq=Wahhabis%20attacked%20the%20city%20of%20Karbala&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q=Wahhabis%20attacked%20the%20city%20of%20Karbala&f=false

Comment: Date would be really helpful.  (1) if the attack didn't happen, I can give you a good estimate of casualties. (2) Casualty estimates in the current day vary widely; historical casualty estimates are notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Is there a reason why the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Karbala) page is inadequate?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I don't think [Wahhabism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahhabism) existed in 7th century CE, so I don't think your link is what the AP is looking for.

Comment: As previous commenters said, a date would really be helpful to narrow down which incident you (OP) mean (if there is such incident at all)

Answer (score 10):

The attack of Wahhabi Muslims on Karbala did happen in history, during the long quest of Wahhabi rise to power in creation of Saudi Arabia. It's just a few years before Wahhabis claimed the city of Mecca and Medina (1803). It was sacked because its role as one of the major center of Shi'i learning; the religious shrines and pilgrimage caravans were destroyed. One of the most notable tomb, the tomb of Husayn bin Ali (the grandson of the Prophet) was also destroyed.

Several authors hold different dates on when the events happened. Some wrote it happened on 1802, however most noted it happened on 1801. Here are some sources I've found noting the incident:

1. Rashid Khalidi, *[Resurrecting Empire](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=1AMo1XECVO4C&lpg=PA105&ots=ifEXXsW_r6&dq=sack%20of%20karbala&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q=sack%20of%20karbala&f=false)*
2. Yitzhak Nakash, *[The Shi'is of Iraq](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=BXJqeTr6p78C&lpg=PA28&ots=z0oxi6ptxI&dq=Wahhabis%20attacked%20the%20city%20of%20Karbala&hl=id&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q=Wahhabis%20attacked%20the%20city%20of%20Karbala&f=false)* (also on [different page](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=BXJqeTr6p78C&lpg=PA241&ots=z0oxi7pvvB&dq=sack%20of%20karbala&pg=PA241#v=onepage&q=sack%20of%20karbala&f=false))
3. Ludwig Adamec, *[A to Z of Islam](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=srXuG7YmxHIC&lpg=PA141&ots=ccqoGrjlmy&dq=sack%20of%20karbala&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=sack%20of%20karbala&f=false)*
4. James Grehan, *[Everyday Life and Consumer Culture in Eighteenth-Century Damascus](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=lGzSqFuEu4MC&lpg=PA53&ots=1fuZUafyvo&dq=sack%20of%20karbala&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q=sack%20of%20karbala&f=false)*
5. Andrew McGregor, *[A Military History of Modern Egypt](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=WrbCziCWJPEC&lpg=PA57&ots=mxYEg5gSfs&dq=sack%20of%20karbala&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q=sack%20of%20karbala&f=false)*
6. Najma Heptula, *[Indo-West Asian Relations](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=BXWFlKwemEQC&lpg=PA48&ots=GsuXtoW8uF&dq=sack%20of%20karbala&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q=sack%20of%20karbala&f=false)*

I haven't been able to find the number of casualties though. Perhaps @MarkCWallace could help on this matter.

Comment: @Ali: I was trying to answer this: "did this attack really happened in history?" by providing works that mention this incident. It's in his question.

Comment: ok but I cant take the DV as its locked

Comment: @Ali: it's okay, just wanting to confirm what I was trying to do.